# Como redondear decimales a enteros?

Tags: java, condiciones, estructuras, redondeo

Realizar un programa de notas  que:

- Pida un nombre
- Pida una nota, que siempre debe estar entre 1 y 10, si se ha introducido una nota incorrecta se deberá volver a pedir hasta que tenga un valor correcto.
- Mostrar un mensaje de, con el nombre del alumno y si su nota ha sido:

APROBADO, si la nota es más que 5 y menor que 6
BIEN, si está mayor que 6 y menor que 7
NOTABLE, si está mayor que 7 y menor que 9
SOBRESALIENTE, si es mayor que 9 o menor o igual a 10
SUSPENSO si es menor a 5

**** Hay que considerar redondear las notas hacia arriba, es decir un 4,5 o más se debe transformar en un 5.*** Y NO SÉ COMO HACERLO

este es mi codigo hasta el momento:

```
public class Act3punto3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String nombre;
        double nota;


        System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        nombre = sc.next();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su nota: ");

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        nota = sc1.nextInt();
        
        

        if (nota >= 0 && nota <= 10) {
            if (nota > 5 && nota < 6) {
                System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Aprobado!!");
            }
            if (nota > 6 && nota < 7) {
                System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Bien!!");
            }
            if (nota > 7 && nota < 9) {
                System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Notable!!");
            }
            if (nota > 9 && nota <= 10) {
                System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Sobresaliente!!");
            }
            if (nota < 5) {
                System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Suspenso!!");
            }
            
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error!! La nota debe ser entre 1 y 10");
            
        }
    }
}
```

No sé como redondear cuando la nota cuando es un decimal

Comment: ya intentaste con `Math.round`?

Comment: Empieza por leer un `double` en lugar de un entero: `sc1.nextDouble();`, luego  usa `Math.ceil` para redondear hacia arriba. Asegúrate de incluir los casos fronterizos en tus condiciones. Por ejemplo `nota = 6` ¿donde cae? No lo estás considerando. Pon el signo `<=` o `>=` correspondiente. Cabe notar que cuando redondees ya no tienes que considerar rangos, si no que puedes preguntar por números específicos usando `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quedaria asi.

```
public class Act3punto3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String nombre;
    Float nota;


    System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre: ");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    nombre = sc.next();

    System.out.println("Introduzca su nota: ");

    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    nota = sc1.nextFloat();
    int redondear = Math.round(nota);      
    nota=(float)redondear ;

    if (nota >= 0 && nota <= 10) {
        System.out.println("entre");
        if (nota >= 5 && nota < 6) {
            System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Aprobado!!");
        }
        if (nota >= 6 && nota < 7) {
            System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Bien!!");
        }
        if (nota >= 7 && nota < 9) {
            System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Notable!!");
        }
        if (nota >= 9 && nota <= 10) {
            System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Sobresaliente!!");
        }
        if (nota < 5) {
            System.out.println(nombre + ", Su nota ha sido: Suspenso!!");
        }
        
    } else {
        System.err.println("Error!! La nota debe ser entre 1 y 10");
        
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el Math.Round(), que redondeará hacía el entero más próximo.

¡Un saludo! (y que no se te olvidé también que tienes un sc1.nextInt(), esto es solo para números enteros, en cuando le metas un numero con decimales te petará)

Comment: Solo copiaste del comentario de Ruslan sin valorar que ni siquiera es correcto dado que el usuario especifica textualmente *"Hay que considerar redondear las notas **hacia arriba**"*. `Math.round` no redondea hacia arriba. Por favor, no insertes este tipo de respuestas. Lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ¿Puedes poner una referencia donde diga que `Math.round` no redondea hacia arriba en Java? Es la primera vez que leo eso y una búsqueda rápida en Google prueba lo contrario: [la documentación oficial sólo dice el entero más cercano](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-) y esta [otra página explica cómo se calcula y cómo sí puede redondear hacia arriba](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-java-mathround-method).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro el entero más cercano **NO es hacia arriba**. 4.4 se redondearía a 4 con `Math.round`. Redondeado "hacia arriba" devolvería 5. `Math.ceil` redondea hacia arriba. La frase `hacia arriba` denota el entero **MAYOR** más cercano.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez `Math.round` redondea hacia arriba y hacia abajo dependiendo del valor del decimal. Por ejemplo, 4.4 se redondeará a 4 (abajo), y 4.6 se redondeará a 5 (arriba). Leyendo el enunciado de la pregunta, no queda claro que siempre se quiera redondear hacia arriba; parece que sólo quiere redondear hacia arriba en x.5 o más ("Hay que considerar redondear las notas hacia arriba, es decir un 4,5 o más se debe transformar en un 5."), por lo que usar `Math.round()` podría ser una opción válida.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yo leo textualmente *"Hay que considerar redondear las notas hacia arriba"*. No se cuál enunciado esté leyendo usted. De cualquier forma, ya es cuestión de interpretación, pero no tengo ningún motivo para pensar que sea válido redondear también hacia abajo cuando hay una nota tan explícita.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez pero la frase continúa: "_Hay que considerar redondear las notas hacia arriba, **es decir un 4,5 o más se debe transformar en un 5**._" ¿quiere eso decir que un 4,4 se redondeará hacia arriba o hacia abajo? Porque leyendo sólo la primera parte, parece que sería hacia arriba, pero leyendo la segunda, yo entendería que es hacia abajo.

Comment: Lo segunda es solo un ejemplo. ¿En que momento ese ejemplo contradice la frase de redondear hacia arriba? No veo la contradicción. De cualquier forma, solo el OP, sabrá lo que quiso decir, pero por lo que está escrito, No hay NINGUNA RAZÓN para redondear hacia abajo.

Comment: Vale, te doy la razón en eso. Pero ese no era a lo que me refería en mi comentario. Yo estaba respondiendo a tu comentario de "`Math.round` no redondea hacia arriba" y ahora estamos discutiendo la semántica de la pregunta que es otro tema diferente. Pero vamos, que no importa tampoco.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro y te respondí en mi primer comentario con un ejemplo. El entero más cercano (como especifica de manera literal la documentación) NO es hacia arriba. Hacia arriba significa el entero MAYOR O IGUAL más cercano. Te puse hasta el ejemplo de 4.4 y cómo Math.Round falla en esto. No se qué mas necesitabas.